# Transform JavaScript Object - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a simple JavaScript nested object as shown below. I don't know how many children will be there, but that's how the nature of the data is that I am receiving.
How can I transform into expected result ?

**Raw Data nested json**

```
{
    "work": {
        "children": {
            "abc": {
                
                "label": "Work address",
                "name": "address"
            },
            "xyz": {
                
                "label": "Work phone",
                "name": "phone"
            },
            "efg": {
                "children": {
                    "position": {
                        
                        "label": "Work",
                        "name": "position"
                    },
                    "employees": {

                        "label": "Number of employees",
                        "name": "employees"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected**

```
{
      work: {
        "address": "",
        "phone": "",
        "details": {
          "position": "",
          "employees": ""
        }
      }
    }
```

**What I have tried is the following code**

```
var jsonschema = root.json
var newjson = {}
for (let name in jsonschema) {
     if (jsonschema.children.length > 0 ) {
          //add a empty object to newjson
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a generic `map` function and a recursive `transform` function -

```js
const map = (f, t) =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(t).map(([ k, v ]) => [ k, f(v) ]))

const transform = (t = {}) =>
  t.name 
    ? ""
    : map(transform, t.children || t)

const input =
  {"work":{"children":{"address":{"component":"BaseInput","label":"Work address","name":"address"},"phone":{"component":"BaseInput","label":"Work phone","name":"phone"},"details":{"children":{"position":{"component":"BaseInput","label":"Work position","name":"position"},"employees":{"component":"BaseInput","label":"Number of employees","name":"employees"}}}}}}
  
console.log(transform(input))
```